# Run my program inside Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to run my program inside Tkinter?

I have a program which fits the curves. I want to make it GUI and looking for the ways to insert it into Tkinter.

I want my program to run after clicking a BUTTON widget.  Is there a option in Tkinter to run another *file.py*?

Comment: What have you found about this subject by searching for it? Doesn't have Tkinter help files?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have read [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program).  The cleanest way of loading the code from another python file is to import it, for example:

```
import myfile

...
mybutton['command'] = myfile.main
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To run another file, you can import it, or load the data with

> file = open("filename.txt", "r")

then use

> exec(*string*)

to run the program inside it.

Comment: `eval` only evaluates statements.  You would need to use `exec` to run a program from a file.